# JSON.parse syntax error validating user info

Tags: php, json, ajax

I've been trying to work out what my problem is for the last 5 hours and all I have to show for it is a pounding headache... please help me...

I'm trying to create a login and registration form; the login part is working fine however the registration one is throwing me a *"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"*. I don't know where this is coming from and how to fix it.

I believe the issue is in the register part of the handler, but other than that I'm clueless:

```
//*************************************************************
  // Register

  else if($requestType == 'Register')
  {
    function complexEnough($pass)
    {
      if (preg_match('/[A-Za-z]/', $pass) && preg_match('/[0-9]/', $pass))
        if (strlen($pass) > 6)
          return true;

      return false;
    }

    try {
      $email = $jsonContent['Email'];
      $username = $jsonContent['Username'];
      $password1 = $jsonContent['Password1'];
      $password2 = $jsonContent['Password2'];

      if ($username == "")
        echo "Registration failed: Username was blank";

      else if ($email == "")
        echo "Registration failed: email address field was blank";

      else if ($password1 != $password2)
        echo "Registration failed: passwords did not match";

      else if ($password1 == "")
        echo "Registration failed: passwords were blank";

      else if (!complexEnough($password1))
      {
        echo "Registration failed: Password must contain an uppercase, lowercase, number and be at least 6 characters long";
      }

      else
      {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=SpaceInvaders', $DbConfig['Uid'], $DbConfig['Password']);

        $query = $db->prepare("insert into users(username, email, password) values (:username, :emailAddress, :password)");
        $query->bindParam(':username', $username);
        $query->bindParam(':emailAddress', $email);
        $hashedPassword = password_hash($password1, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $query->bindParam(':password', $hashedPassword);
        $result = $query->execute();

        if ($result)
          $jsonResponse = array( 'ErrorCode' => '0', 'Message' => "");
        else
          $jsonResponse = array( 'ErrorCode' => '3', 'Message' => "Email Address already allocated");

        $query = null;
        $db = null;
      }
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
      $jsonResponse = array( 'ErrorCode' => '1', 'Message' => "Unexpected Error:" . $e->getMessage());
    }
    echo json_encode($jsonResponse);
  }
```

P.S. - I know there'll be stuff that isn't 'best practice', It's only an introductory course to web scripting.

Comment: Have you viewed the content coming back from this script, can you see the actual string your expecting to be JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check JSON what you get from the request and validate it with any online JSON validator services. I'm sure you're getting invalid JSON and you need to check how you form it.